# How to set custom permission's protectionLevel dynamically from build.gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-manifest

I would like to set an android permission's `protectionLevel` dynamically depending on debug or release, say, from the `build.gradle` file, something like this:

The `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.somestring.MY_CUSTOM_PERMISSION"
    android:protectionLevel=BuildConfig.protectionlevel />
```

And the `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
          buildConfigField "String" , "protectionlevel" , "signature"     
        }
        debug{
          buildConfigField "String" , "protectionlevel" , "normal"
        }
    }
}
```

Setting variables from `build.gradle` in this way works in java / other cases, but does not work for `signature`. I have tried some other variations that you can find in a quick Google search, but so far, I could not make it work for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually [manifest placeholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables) can be used:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [protectionLevel: "signature"]  
    }
    debug{
        manifestPlaceholders = [protectionLevel: "normal"] 
    }
}
```

And then:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.somestring.MY_CUSTOM_PERMISSION"
    android:protectionLevel="${protectionLevel}" />
```